# inet_ntop returns wrong IPv6

Tags: c++, c, inet

I'm using a library and one of its functions returns `struct sockaddr*` object.
Now, I'm trying to print out the IP address return by the function via this code:

```
char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = {0};

switch(sa->sa_family) {
    case AF_INET: {
        struct sockaddr_in *addr_in = (struct sockaddr_in *) sa;
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(addr_in->sin_addr), s, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        break;
    }
    case AF_INET6: {
        struct sockaddr_in6 *addr_in6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) sa;
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(addr_in6->sin6_addr), s, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
        break;
    }

    default:
        break;
}
```

According to the outputs, I see no problem with IPv4 translation to string, however when it tries to convert IPv6 address to string there will be issues. What i can see so far is that there is an unknown / extra hex string appends to IPv6 address.

```
Real IPv6 address: 2a03:ef42:6:63f3::
My Conversation:   2a03:ef42:6:63f3:e057:d198:1a7f:0
```

The library itself provides some kinda debug/dump printing option and what I can see is that the IPv6 addresses are getting printed out just fine.

Can anybody point me to problem.

Thanks

Comment: A full IPv6 address representation consists of those 8 parts which are printed. I don't see what should be wrong with it, or why you expect something different?

Comment: Usually ipv6 string contains the format `x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x` where any x is a hexadecimal string representing a 16-bit value

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, my issue with my output is that it is actually different with the one that library itself logged for the IPv6 address. the first and shorter result is logged by the library (for the same IPv6 address that I'm trying to translate) and It is why think there is something wrong with my output.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to inspect the values in `addr_in6->sin6_addr`? I'm guessing `inet_ntop` is working correctly and just `addr_in6->sin6_addr` doesn't contain what you expect it to

Comment: As an alternative, you can use `getnameinfo()` instead, specifying the `NI_NUMERICHOST` flag. You can pass in the original `sockaddr*` as-is and let `getnameinfo()` figure out the IP string formatting for you.

Comment: Thank you @RemyLebeau :) It actually resolved my problem !!